# EF6 Code Migration - Data manipulation in order to update a column 'filePath' to varbinary

Tags: c#, entity-framework, code-migration

I have done a few changes to the data model and I'm required to update an entity 'File'. Previously, this entity had only a reference to an absolute path.

My intention is to fetch the file through its path and stream it to a varbinary column.

Is it reliable/advisable to do this manipulation together/during the respective Entity Framework's Code-Migration?
This migration will be inflicted on a project where multiple developers are involved. 
I am trying to figure out what is the most automated way of achieving this migration.

Are there any guidelines/approaches for these sorts of migrations ?

Comment: Wow that sounds cool and all but why? I'm just curious :)

Comment: @Heberda There are certain files that we cannot serve statically. We store them using sql filestream and serve them to the user with a file controller.

Comment: Interesting, thanks for replying :) Good luck with the solution, it's a bit above my level haha

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I always prefer to do this kind of jobs in the `Up()` method of the migration.

Remember that you have all the .NET functionality at your fingertips. In this way, wherever you apply the migration, the database will get updated.

As your file paths are absolute, there is no problem to find them in the system where the application runs.

Comment: Seems the way to go, I'll just wait a couple of days to mark it as answered, In the event of anyone else participating.

Answer (score 1):

I would create the fileData (varbinary) and keep the filePath (varchar) for the time being. This change could be done by the migration. Then I would transfer the data from file to byte array in a separate job, through a console application or something similar, syncing this action with the other developers.

With this setup you could also select to lazy-transfer the files, e.g. when a file is requested you load it from the file and save it in the varbinary.

Then, in a later migration, when you've verified that all data is transferred, you could delete the filePath column.

Comment: That sounds reasonable, however I would prefer to automatize the process a bit more.